# React - combine immediate input and debounced output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component within a component. The parent component (Form) is expensive to render because of complex caluculations. Because of this if I hold down a key in the username input in the child component (UserForm) the page starts dropping frames (new characters don't show for a bit) because it renders the parent (which is expensive) as quickly as possible. To solve this I started storing a local instance of the username prop into state in the child component and then debouncing that state before passing it up to the parent.

The issue is when the parent component modifies the username (such as by reverting the changes) while the debounce in the child component is still in progress, the parent component's modification is overwritten by the child component's debounced output.

```
const UserForm = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  const debouncedOnChange = useCallback(
    lodash.debounce(updatedValue => {
      onChange(updatedValue);
    }, 500),
    [onChange]
  );

  const [username, setUsername] = useState(value.username);
  useEffect(() => {
    setUsername(value.username);
  }, [value.username]);

  const handleUsernameOnChange = useCallback(
    event => {
      setUsername(event.target.value);
      debouncedOnChange({
        ...value,
        username: event.target.value,
      });
    },
    [debouncedOnChange]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={username} onChange={handleUsernameOnChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: {
    username: 'John',
  },
  dog: {
    name: 'Cliffard'
  }
};

// <Form/> Is expensive to render because of complex calculations
const Form = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);

  const [backup, setBackup] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);

  return (
    <form>
      <UserForm
        value={value.user}
        onChange={updatedUserFormValue => {
          setValue({
            ...value,
            updatedUserFormValue,
          });
        }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setValue({
            ...value,
            user: { ...backup.user },
          });
        }}
      >
        Reset User Form
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why _rendering_ involves complex calculations? It should only contain rendering proper, and maybe triggering events to be processed asynchronously (like keypresses).

Comment: There is a list of hundreds of <UserForm/>s in <Form/>. There are many rules that check whether the fields in those hundreds of <UserForms/>s conflict with each other.

Comment: (1) You should do that conflict checking in your action(s) which change the list, and store the result in the state; then you'd do it only when the list changes, and will render the unchanged list quickly. (2) Consider only rendering the visible part of the list (plus some for safety).